# Crear función recursiva

Tags: java, recursión

Necesito de su ayuda para crear una función recursiva para imprimir los niveles de profundidad de un objeto.

Este es el código feo:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println(baul.metal);
  System.out.println(baul.baul.metal);
  System.out.println(baul.baul.baul.metal);
  System.out.println(baul.baul.baul.baul.metal);
  System.out.println(baul.baul.baul.baul.baul.metal);
}
```

Necesito remplazar este código por una función recursiva.

Comment: Esta pregunta pertenece a un examen que realizamos en TV Azteca, lo cual me ayuda a cambiarlo para los próximos candidatos.

Answer (score 2):

Tomando en cuenta que es una instancia de una clase:

```
public class Baul {

    private String metal;
    private Baul baul;

    public void imprime() {
        System.out.println(this.metal);
        if (this.baul != null) {
            this.baul.imprime();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Esa función no esta correcta, le falta el parámetro, entre otras cosas que no dan claridad.

Answer (score 0):

Después de darle vueltas creo que la **solución a crear un método para imprimir los niveles de profundidad** de la clase Baul es la siguiente:

```
public void imprime() {
        if (this.baul != null) {
            System.out.print("baul.");
            this.baul.imprime();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(this.metal);
        }
    }
```

**La clase Baul** donde encaja dicho método es la siguiente:

```
public class Baul {

    private String metal = new String("metal");
    private Baul baul = null;
    private static int nLevels = 3;

    public Baul() {
        if (Baul.nLevels>0)
        {
            Baul.nLevels = Baul.nLevels - 1;
            baul = new Baul();  
        }
    }
    public void imprime() {
        if (this.baul != null) {
            System.out.print("baul.");
            this.baul.imprime();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(this.metal);
        }
    }
    public static void setLevels(int nLevels) {
        Baul.nLevels = nLevels;
    }   
}
```

Esta clase **Baul hace uso de una variable estática para crear una instancia con una produndidad marcada previamente**.

Finalmente, **con el siguiente test podemos comprobar el funcionamiento de la clase Baul**.

```
public class TestBaul {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Baul.setLevels(5);
        Baul baul = new Baul();
        baul.imprime();
        Baul baul2 = new Baul();
        baul2.imprime();
        Baul.setLevels(2);
        Baul baul3 = new Baul();
        baul3.imprime();
    }

}
```

**El resultado obtenido es:**

```
baul.baul.baul.baul.baul.metal
metal 
baul.baul.metal
```